# Mathematical operators to use to give following result

Tags: math

I have a scenario where if the user has the following input, I would like the following output:

```
x -> y
2 -> 1
1 -> 0
0 -> 0
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this through a function? The closest I can get is:

```
y = x-1
```

But that doesn't work for the 0->0 case.

Note that modulus or absolute values or anything I can evaluate with a programming language is fair game.

Comment: you wan't this in php?

Comment: Hint: convert the x values to binary.

Comment: What happens to 3? Does that go to 2 or to 1?

Comment: It can never be anything besides 0, 1, 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In languages such as C, C++, Objective-C, Java, etc, with a right shift operator (`>>`) you could just do this:

```
y = x >> 1;
```

Failing that, integer division would also work:

```
y = x / 2;
```

Comment: Perfect!  One followup.  How would I get the results:  2->0, 1->1, 0->1?

Comment: Since that's just the complement of the original requirement you can do something like `y = (x >> 1) ^ 1;` or `y = (x / 2) ^ 1;`